# solving for integration limits numerically?

Tags: python, matlab, area, curve, numerical-integration

I am trying to locate a region under the curve of two functions such that the area of this region equals a given number `m`. For example, by integrating the two functions:

```
f(x) = 3x - 3x^2
g(x) = x
```

symbolically from a to b, and equating each to m (e.g. m=1/3). The system can be solved to find the values of a and b:

```
1.5 b^2 - b^3 - 1.5 a^2 + a^3 = 1/3
0.5 b^2 - 0.5 a^2 = 1/3
```

The positive solution I got to this is approximately: `a = 0.364823, b = 0.894294`

Now, my question is: how can I find a and b if f and g were given to me as vectors (or arrays in python) instead of symbolic functions? I know how to use `trapz()` to find areas for vectors but I don't know if there is a way to use it to find `a` and `b` in the above problem numerically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/index.html)

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x,a,b = symbols('x a b')
>>> fx = "3*x - 3*x**3"
>>> gx = "x"
>>> m = 1/3
>>> int_fx = integrate(fx, (x,a,b))
3*a**4/4 - 3*a**2/2 - 3*b**4/4 + 3*b**2/2
>>> int_gx = integrate(gx, (x,a,b))
-a**2/2 + b**2/2
>>> solve([Eq(int_fx, m), Eq(int_gx, m)],(a, b))
[(-0.577350269189626, -1.00000000000000), (-0.577350269189626, 1.00000000000000), (0.577350269189626, -1.00000000000000), (0.577350269189626, 1.00000000000000)]
```

By the way, I am having hard time to understand how you managed to get a definite integral solution of

```
1.5 b^2 - b^3 - 1.5 a^2 + a^3 = 1/3
```

for

```
f(x) = 3x - 3x^3
```

within

```
[a,b]
```

Comment: Sorry, it should have been f(x) = 3x - 3x^2 instead of 3x - 3x^3. Thanks for the code by the way, but I actually understand how to code that in python/matlab when fx and gx are 'symbolic'. My question was how to gain equivalent results if fx and gx were given only as vectors (i.e. points) instead of symbolic functions??

Comment: @user1583416: Can you rephrase your original question? The original question deals with symbolic

Comment: I used the symbolic example only to show what I want to accomplish equivalently in numeric (i.e. to find a and b that make area under curve of f and g equal to value m, where f and g are given as vectors (points)).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at integral equations: [Numerical Recipes](http://www.mpi-hd.mpg.de/astrophysik/HEA/internal/Numerical_Recipes/f18-0.pdf) and [SO](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4677/solving-a-volterra-integral-equation-numerically), for example.